# Is horizontal and vertical scrolling on the same page possible?

Tags: javascript, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to build a website that moves to sections using arrow keys on the keyboard or swipe on mobile/tablets. I am using FullPage. Is it possible to have a grid like website where the user can move in a square grid like fashion rather then just up and down?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But might be much easier without fullpage.js

- So you could have the page fixed but it content overflow. So that would allow you to be able to scroll at all direction.
- You could add a mouse listener to scrollTo(x,y). Where x and y are the mouse pointer location

Comment: With fullpage.js when i scroll down it snaps to the next section. Can that happen on the X too, the snapping? In excel spreadsheet talk. A1, A2, A3 (normal scrolling down site website). Iwant A1, A2, B2, C2, C3, B3, A3. snapping to each section. Is this possible?

Comment: you could try it with the css scroll snap